# How do you trigger the "error" callback in a jQuery AJAX call using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

This is related to my question on [how to handle errors from jQuery AJAX calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407596/how-do-you-handle-errors-from-ajax-calls).  Several responses suggested that I use the "error" callback to display any errors from a jQuery AJAX call.  I was wondering how to do that using ASP.NET MVC.  Is there a way for my controller action to return an error that would be accessible from the "error" callback?  The client side code would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "MyUrl",
   data: "val1=test",
   success: function(result){
        // Do stuff
   },
   error: function(request,status,errorThrown) {

   }
 });
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

NOTE: Hey, this was posted before ASP.Net MVC even hit 1.0, and I haven't even looked at the framework since then. You should probably stop upvoting this.

---

Do something like this:

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
actionResult = this.Content("Error message here");
```

The status code should change depending on the nature of the error; generally, 4xx for user-generated problems and 5xx for server-side problems.

Comment: Have you tried it in IE8? The request.responseText property contains null, there is not the 'Error message here' string :(

Answer (score 8):

If you're using

```
[HandleError]
```

then throwing a **HttpException** is going to get caught and routed to your custom error page.

Another option is to use

```
Response.StatusCode = 500;
Response.Write("Error Message");
Response.End();
```

There's probably a more convenient way to write this but I haven't stumbled upon it yet.

Comment: Yeah, the [HandleError] attribute was what was getting me.  It was catching my exceptions and redirecting to my error page.  Unfortunately this attribute was on the controller class so I didn't see it immediately.

Comment: I believe you marked an incorrect answer. I would favor ALassek's answer over the HttpException which is technically wrong.

Comment: Does this work in all browsers?  This to me would seem to be the more correct answer...

Answer (score 8):

If you're using MVC 3, then you can return an ActionResult in your controller that has the HTTP status code and status message together:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, "Error message");
```

Then, in your error callback:

```
error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(request.statusText);
}
```

Comment: I wonder what the code is behind new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, "Error message"); is.  Is the source someplace or maybe we can reflector it?  Probably be helpful for those of us in 2.

Comment: @rball - The code is on codeplex at the following link: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/50092

Comment: That takes me to the entire source.  Not sure if I clicked on the wrong thing, but even just casually sifting through the source didn't find anything.  I'll have to download and see if I can find it through the IDE.

Comment: +1 for the HttpStatusCodeResult() object... but "Error message" is [never returned to the browser](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/07/28/asp-net-mvc-3-creating-httpstatuscoderesult-with-view-based-body.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think that event is raised for any response that has a response code other than 200. I can't find proof of this in the docs though.

To do this from code (works in Webforms):

```
throw new HttpException(500, "Error message");
```

Comment: How do you send a response code other than 200 from a controller action though?  Let's say my controller action determines that the user doesn't have the right to access the function and I want to return a response code other than 200 so that the "error" callback is hit.  How would I do this?

Comment: Hmm, would throwing an exception from the controller action do the trick?  That should send back a 500 response code right?

Comment: Edited the answer to provide a possible way of doing it

Comment: I think maybe this answer combined with Todd's first way would be the complete way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/4480642a3824bd60) page, you just need to apply the header `HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error` on your ASP.net page. The `$.ajax` request will catch that error and execute the `error` callback function. =]

Answer (score 1):

I send you a proposal; works with contrelled and uncontrolled exceptions.

```
  public class CodeExceptionToHttpFilter : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public CodeExceptionToHttpFilter()
    {
      Order = 2;
    }
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
      var codeException = filterContext.Exception as CodeException;
      var response = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response;
  response.StatusCode = (codeException == null)? 550: 551;
      response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain;
      response.Charset = "utf-8";
      response.Write(filter.Exception.Message);
      filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
      response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
   }
```

}

More info on my blog.
http://rodrigopb.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/gestion-de-errores-en-peticiones-ajax-a-mvc/