# How should asp.net(mvc) server return error to jquery ajax call to be caught in error callback?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, callback

Suppose I have a method in my controller that is called via a jQuery AJAX call. E.g. I'd like to delete a user. When everything goes fine, I return new Content('ok') and exit the method.

What should I do when an error occured? I'd like to indicate it by an appropriate status code, so that my error call back would be called called. Why status code? Read here: 
[How do you trigger the "error" callback in a jQuery AJAX call using ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/407651/61654)

However, the approach doesn't work because IIS7 returns it's own message (Bad request) insted of my custom error message.

Besides that there are two other catches:

1. It has to work with IIS6 as well
2. IE8 doesn't return the 'Bad request' string. Inside error callback the property request.responseTest is null.

The error callback could look like this:
error: function(request) { alert(request.responseText);}

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Setting the Response.StatusCode is the correct thing to do. To fix IIS's "helpful" error handling, set the [HttpResponse.TrySkipIisCustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors.aspx) property. You can read more about this [here](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/745738.aspx).

Comment: The IIS 7 behavior you're seeing is unique to IIS 7 and must be addressed specifically. Read the links in my answer.

Comment: Probably I don't understand. The links provided are only about IIS 7, but I need a solution for IIS 6 as well (as pointed in (1))

Comment: IIS 6 doesn't replace 500 errors in the way that IIS 7 does. But the MVC framework will if you throw an exception and "catch" it with [HandleError]. Those are two entirely separate problems. Similarly for any custom error handling you define in Web.config. Your post describes a real problem with IIS 7, and I gave you the fix for that. You *may* also be experiencing an entirely separate problem with similar symptoms that also shows up in IIS 6, but (1) there *will not* be one solution which fixes both problems, and (2) there isn't enough info in your question to diagnose the second issue.

Comment: If I could vote for this 10x, I would. I just went through 1.5 days of pain trying to figure this out. Thanks!!!

Comment: Mark Struzinski... we are 2! =)