# How to send a server error response using php?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, response

As soon as the user clicks the *delete button* my jQuery script asks the server to delete the selected item.

Now I want my **php** script to send a success or an error response.

Is it possible to **fire the error callback** in case the item could not be deleted?

Thanks

---

my jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "post",
 url: "myAjax.php" ,
 dataType: "text",
 data: {
  some:data
 }, 
 error: function(request,error) 
 {
         // tell the user why he couldn't delete the item
         // timeout , item not found ...
 },

 success: function ( response )
 {
      // tell the user that the item was deleted
         // hide the item
 }
);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
header('HTTP', true, 500); // 500 internal server error
// etc etc..
```

Check out [header()](http://php.net/header) for more options. All the HTTP error codes are available for use.

Related question: [How do you trigger the "error" callback in a jQuery AJAX call using ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407651/how-do-you-trigger-the-error-callback-in-a-jquery-ajax-call-using-asp-net-mvc)