# How to Alert the returned data of ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jQuery page with AJAX, and is submitted in a separate PHP file that has no UI. so what i want is if say for example an insert query in my PHP file will fail, an `echo(your insert failed)` in my PHP will be alerted in my jQuery page. how to do that?

something like this `alert(data);`

Comment: I think what you actually want to say is: "how to return data about error from php and display it on page". Am I right?

Comment: I edited my answer, hopefully it is what you are looking for

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT 2:**

Alerting anything that PHP echos:

```
function get_data() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_data.php?rand=' + Math.random(),
        type: 'GET'
        success: function(results) { 
            alert(results);
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

If you want the errors to appear in an alert, do this:

for debugging ajax, you can check the xhr, status, and error like so:

```
function get_data() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_data.php?rand=' + Math.random(),
        type: 'GET',
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(status);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        },
        success: function(results) { 
            /* clear old results, then display the new results */
            $("#divResults").empty().append(results);
        }
    });
}
```

But this might not always display the full message, especially if the error message contains lots of data.  it might end up going off the screen.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

for debugging ajax, you can check the xhr, status, and error like so:

```
function get_data() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_data.php?rand=' + Math.random(),
        type: 'GET',
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            /* clear old error message, then display the new php error message */
            $("#divErrorMessages").empty().append(status);
            $("#divErrorMessages").append(xhr.responseText);
        },
        success: function(results) { 
            /* clear the error message first */
            $("#divErrorMessages").empty();

            /* clear old results, then display the new results */
            $("#divResults").empty().append(results);
        }
    });
}
```

In your HTML you should have the 2 divs

```
<div id="divResults"></div>
<div id="divErrorMessages"></div>
```

Comment: i want it to be displayed as alert only. not in div

Comment: and i am not alerting errors. i am alerting what is echoed in PHP. not necessarily errors.

Comment: If that is the case, then you just need to alert what is returned in the success function.  Check out edit 2

Answer (score 1):

You can use `success` handler in `$.ajax` call as diEcho wrote.
Inside of this handler, you can decide by some flag whether your PHP operation succeeded or failed.

`error` handler of `$.ajax` is more likely for ajax call fail, than for status of requested operation.

Edit:

applying to  example by diEcho:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/post/post_url.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: parameters,
  success: function(data){
    alert('ajax call finished successfully');
    if (!data.insertedOk) {
      alert(data.message);
    } else {
      // insert succeeded
    }
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('ajax call failure');
    // this mean, /post/post_url.php calling failed (file not found etc...)
  }
});
```

EDIT2:

in PHP you could use following

```
if ($queryExecutedSuccessfully) {
    $return['insertedOk'] = true;
    $return['message'] = 'Your success message';
} else {
    $return['insertedOk'] = false;
    $return['message'] = 'Error message when insert fails.';
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: where did you get insertd0k? is it a variable in php page?

Comment: all i want to do is to make my echo in php alerted in my other jquery page on ajax success.

Comment: check out EDIT2 in the answer

Comment: can i use that json_encode anytime? is it a php function? or i have to download a plugin for that?

Comment: it's PHP built in function... check out its manual page to see how to use it

Comment: but i think your code will only alert "inserted" or "insert failed". how to alert "your success message" or "error message when insert fails"?

Comment: Check my answer, it does exactly what you want, i.e. display whatever php error you get on your jquery page.

Comment: your code doesnt work. and it makes my whole code to not work too.

Comment: @user628961 - well, I though you see the principle... I've just edited my answer again to output whatever is sent in `message`

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/post/post_url.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: parameters,
  success: function(){
    alert('success');
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('failure');
  }
});
```

[Reference](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax)

Comment: I think is not true, because the script PHP are execute without error (the logic has an error, not the process), then the return code will be always 'success'.

Comment: You can add a parameter to the success function `success: function(data) { ... }`, which holds the response from the server. Your function can then contain `alert(data);` to show the actual response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the code of @diEcho, You also need to test in `success: function()` your returned answer with a status code (wrote by PHP).

In other hand, you can force the error in your PHP script by sending an "Error 500" header, that generate the "Fail" callback.
But it's not a good way !

In your PHP:

```
if (true === $QueryHasFail) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error'); // <--- Ajax Callback error: function() 
    echo "Oupss, somethink wrong!";
} else {
    echo "Yeah, great"; // <--- Ajax Callback success: function()
}
exit(0);
```

More information here: http://www.rachaelarnold.com/dev/archive/trigger-ajax-error-event

Comment: I've added an example of "500header" method

Answer (score 0):

**To alert what is echoed in your PHP, "data" is passed into the success function as the first parameter, which is then output in an alert in this example:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/post/post_url.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: parameters,
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert('Failure: ' + textStatus + ". Error thrown: " + errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Comment: what is textStatus and jqXHR? all i want to do is alert what is echoed in my php.

Comment: If you want to do that, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but as i found it searching for something similar, i decided to add some information that could be useful for later searches.

I think **a solution** to this could be aproached by **sending** the appropriate **header() or http_response_code($HTTP_ERROR_CODE)**; in your **PHP Script**, depending on the answers of your PHP Script. You can find related info in this posts:

[How to make a ajax call to a php page a success or error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099492/how-to-make-a-ajax-call-to-a-php-page-a-success-or-error)

[How to send a server error response using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632159/how-to-send-a-server-error-response-using-php)

**The function you select** (header or http_response_code) it depends on the version of PHP you are using, it seems that http_response_code is available from PHP 5.4.

A workaround to avoid "PHP version crosscompiling" might be achieved by coding your own http_response_code in the case that testing for it existance results in failure, as is suggested in this other post of php.net:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Latter, on your HTML/jQuery document, you can check your request.fail, request.done and request.always to retrieve the information provided by your PHP Script to use it at your convenience.

Hope this helps.