# How to make a ajax call to a php page a success or error?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to send an ajax request to a php page with jquery. But I want to define my success and error functions. I can do this, but in the request php page, how do I get it to be a success or error, like is there some special function I need to call or something, which results in my defined success or error function executing?

EDIT:

I tried this, but it gives me success, even if I switch the http_response_code code to 403.

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "sqlhandler.php?memberID=<?php $memberID ?>",
      success: function(){
        alert("success");
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("error");
      }
    });
```

sqlhandler.php

```
<?php
    http_response_code(200);
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throw 200 for good response and 4xx for bad response: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

If the user tries to see something they shouldn't, use `http_response_code(403);` (forbidden).

If they try looking at something that doesn't exist, use 404.

If you just don't like them, use 403 as a catch-all.

For more information on catching these error codes in jQuery: http://www.unseenrevolution.com/jquery-ajax-error-handling-function Here is an example copied from that page:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So in the end of the php code in my request page, I just need to set it to be 400, if I want it to fail, and 200 if I want it to succeed?

Comment: Yup. After setting the error code, you can `echo` some content to display, then `exit`.

Comment: But when I send a request to that page, it doesn't actually switch to the page, it just sends the request in the background, so how can you see the echo text?

Comment: jQuery is sending an ajax request to a php page, right? The php page handling that request should send a response. jQuery can catch that response and show it to the user.

Comment: `400` does not mean 'generic error'; it means that there is a syntactical error in the request, e.g. malformed JSON. `403` means 'generic error'; despite the intuitive meaning of 'forbidden', it means that the server understands the request but, for an undisclosed reason, refuses to fulfill it

Comment: so if I echo something, then is `jqXHR.responseText` the value of that echo?

Comment: Yes, jqXHR.responseText should have the echoed string.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP status code is the way of indicating whether a request succeeds or fails.

PHP's `http_response_code` sets the status code.

In the object you pass to `$.ajax`, you could define the `error` member as a catch-all for all `3xx`, `4xx`, or `5xx` status codes, or you could define the `statusCode` object to handle each status code with a different function.

Answer (score 1):

When you make any HTTP (AJAX or whatever) call, there are response codes. There are many, for example error code 200 means OK, 4xx calls means error (for example, 404 means "page not found" error).

You should do some research about them.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the following code:

```
.done(function(msg){
if(msg==1)
   alert("Success");
else
   alert("Failure");
})
```

Depending on what you pass from your PHP script, you can alter your code.